# Using checksums to access the civicrm/user dashboard

Tags: checksum, user-dashboard

I was under the impression that adding

`https://civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1&cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}`

to in a CiviMail would log someone in to the dashboard but it does not seem to be working for me.

This answer also suggests it so maybe I am doing something wrong.

PS I also tried id in place of cid (see below) but it did not work either.

`https://civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1&id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}`

PS https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contact/Page/View/UserDashBoard.php does not mention checksums so i am guessing it is not possible...

Answer (score 3):

This works now using the following URL

/civicrm/user?reset=1&id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}

Answer (score 2):

Checksums can only be used for visitor facing forms like event registration, membership sign up or profile forms. If you have drupal as frontend you can also use it in the webform module. It is not usable for backend screens.

Also see http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens

Comment: Hey there Catorghans, https://civicrm.org/civicrm/user?reset=1 is visitor facing so is a valid candidate for a checksum. Maybe you thought I was thinking about https://civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1 which is a backend screen (confusing terminology of CiviCRM's part, I agree).

Comment: Though it is kind of irrelevant since as far as I can tell, checksum has not been enabled for that 'form'. Just thought it was worth mentioning the above because there is no reason why it shouldn't be added.

Comment: ah, thanks, seems you're right in both comments.

Comment: michael - totally agree - dashboard - and things that one should then be able to do from there - like 'update my recurring payment' should be accessible via a checksum - any chance you made a start on anything?

Comment: hey @petednz-fuzion - I missed this message. Nope is the answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, we have the PR if you want to review

Answer (score 2):

I've opened a Gitlab issue for this requirement - https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/162.

Also submitted a patch for this against master branch of the core repository - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12254

UPDATE - the patch is accepted and should be a part of 5.2.0 version.

Comment: can you check if this is covered in documentation?